# any tutorial on Elmah?

Tags: asp.net, elmah, error-logging

I am not able to find any step - to-step tutorial for ElMah- The error logging facility. Basically, I found some articles but they are all vague. For example, I found this article a bit better any other articles out there :

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx

But it has serious problems for example the author says that you have to add few "HTTPHendlers and HttpModules": what does he mean? what he means when he says SOME HttpHandlers? Does anybody have any idea about any good tutorial that can guide from basics?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Nuget package console and type 'Install-Package ELMAH'

Heres a guide on how to get Nuget working

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/Using-the-Package-Manager-Console

Job Done.

Comment: Surely it does not just entail installing a nuget package? How does one configure and set it up? Wheres it going to log to?

Answer (score 3):

Have a read through this

VB - http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/logging-error-details-with-elmah-vb

C# - http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/logging-error-details-with-elmah-cs

Read about httphandlers here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5c67a8bd(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 3):

I've written an [ELMAH Tutorial](http://blog.elmah.io/elmah-tutorial/) which should answer your questions. The tutorial shows you how to install and configure ELMAH step by step. I've extracted the important parts into this answer, but check out the link for more details.

1. Install ELMAH by running the following command (or through the NuGet dialog in Visual Studio:

   Install-Package ELMAH
2. Start your project and navigate to:

   [Your URL]/elmah.axd
3. ELMAH shows you a list of all the logged errors. This will be empty on the first load.
4. Generate a new error by throwing an exception from your code. If you visit /elmah.axd again, the exception will be logged.

The steps above use the in-memory logger. ELMAH comes with a lot of different options like SQL Server, MySql and XML.

Answer (score 1):

The [ELMAH wiki](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/w/list) has detailed instructions on setting up and configuring ELMAH for several different backing stores.

If you are using Visual Studio 2010 and NuGet, there are several different ELMAH packages that will download, setup and configure a website to use ELMAH.